# DenseNet results zero-plan

Tags: conv-neural-network

I am learning about densenet and image reconstruct from speckle.

I take a speckle images form my experiment. Then I run the densenet, it works!
I successfully reconstruct original image from speckle.

But I met some problem after I take more test.

I trained two model with same data from the beginning. One model works well. But another model puts out only zeros.

I don't understand why these results come out.

Could you please explain why the model predicts zeros or how I can check the weights?

I looked at this links
https://github.com/shuailizju/IDiffNet
https://github.com/liuzhuang13/DenseNet

Could you please explain why the model predicts zeros or how I can check the weights?

Comment: trained 2 models? see the differences, ought to be different somewhere

Comment: I can't find differences because I made 2 model with same code, trained same data. only difference is when I trained.

Comment: then see the weight init step, randomisation at different time is always different

Comment: or maybe u create 2 instances of model class but training on static properties